# Awk print matching exact column contents

Tags: awk

```
echo -e "55 11\n25 11.0" | awk '$2 ~ /11/{print $1}'
```

I only want to match "11", and not "11.0"'s value 25. Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match the whole field:

```
% echo -e "55 11\n25 11.0" | awk '$2 ~ /^11$/{print $1}'
55
```

If you *did* want to match numerically, you should not use a regular expression, of course (your current one would also match 6119.42):

```
% echo -e "55 11\n25 11.0" | awk '$2 == 11 { print $1 }'
55
25
```

Comment: +1 for `==` -- you don't need regular expressions for everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e "55 11\n25 11.0" | awk '$2 ~ /^11$/ {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure last field does not contain a decimal point.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo -e "55 11\n25 11.0" | awk '$NF!~/\./{print $1}'
55
```

Comment: Given the title of the question is "print matching exact column contents" this is a little too permissive.

Comment: @Johnsyweb I agree, I couldn't come up with a better solution then yours so just made an attempt to solve it. Should I go ahead and delete it?